# Как передать дополнительный параметр в map python

Tags: python

Всем привет! Подскажи, есть ли возможность в python передать параметр в map

```
with Pool(10) as p:
    try: info = p.map(get_info_hubr, links)
    except: info = []

def get_info_hubr(link:str)->dict:
    """
    Получаем данные со статьи
    """

    hubr_parser = HubrParser(link)
    name_article = hubr_parser.get_name()
    author = hubr_parser.get_authors()
    links = hubr_parser.get_links()
    date = hubr_parser.get_date()
    subjects = hubr_parser.get_subjects()

    return create_dict(name_article, date, author, link, links, subjects)
```

Идея такова: хочу передавать парсер (объект парсера) в качестве параметра в метод get_info_hubr для того что бы метод был не зависим от конкретной реализации парсера. В данном случае реализация для ресурса Hubr, но так же есть реализации под другие ресурсы

Comment: Посмотрите `starmap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно поможет использование `lambda`

```
def get_info_hubr(hubr_parser: HubrParser, link:str)->dict:
    pass  # Оставляем почти без изменений

#------------------

parser_object = HubrParser()
with Pool(10) as p: 
   try: info = p.map(lambda link: get_info_hubr(parser_object, link), links) 
   except: info = []
```

Кроме того, можно использовать `functools.partial`, в сущности это та же `lambda`, но немного быстрее, если верить [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11828489/4710144), а также во многих случаях, код становится более читаемый.

Например

```
def get_info_hubr(hubr_parser: HubrParser, link:str)->dict:
    pass  # Оставляем почти без изменений

#-----------
from functools import partial

with Pool(10) as p:
    try: info = p.map(partial(get_info_hubr, hubr_parser=HubrParser()), links)
    except: info = []
```

Comment: Благодарю! То,что нужно